# Java : newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor is not giving expected result when used parallel to akka framework

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

Using Akka framework for my use case where I created one SupervisorActor and two child actors now parallel to that I have token service which needs to update my cache before the expiry please find the code :

```
public class TokenCacheService {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenCacheService.class);
    private static final String KEY = "USER_TOKEN";
    private LoadingCache<String, String> tokenCache;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService cacheScheduler;
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("MyCacheRefresher-pool-%d").setDaemon(true)
            .build();

    public UserTokenCacheService(CacheConfig cacheConfig) {
        cacheScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory);
        buildCache(cacheConfig);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        String token = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        try {
            token = tokenCache.get(KEY);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            logger.debug("unable to process get token...");
        }
        return token;
    }

    private void buildCache(CacheConfig cacheConfig) {
        tokenCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(4, "HOURS")
                .expireAfterWrite(5, "HOURS")
                .maximumSize(2)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
                    public String load(String queryKey) {
                        logger.debug("cache load()");
                        return <token method call which return token>
                    }

                    @Override
                    @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
                    public ListenableFutureTask<String> reload(final String key, String prevToken) {
                        logger.debug("cache reload()");
                        ListenableFutureTask<String> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(() -> return <token method call which return token>);
                        cacheScheduler.execute(task);
                        return task;
                    }
                });
        cacheScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> tokenCache.refresh(KEY), 0,
                4, "HOURS");
    }
}
```

It is working fine with test class :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TokenCacheService userTokenCacheService = new TokenCacheService();
        while(true){
            System.out.println(tokenCacheService.getToken());
            Thread.sleep(180000);
        }
    }
```

above method printing correct logs as after 4 hours which is expected but when I run the above code with my actual application (with Akka-actors) I can only see the first log `cache load()` apart from this it isn't printing further log for reload the cache.

Please suggest what am doing wrong here.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the actor code.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the code little bit by setting the priority to 1 and replaced `scheduleWithFixedDelay` with `scheduleAtFixedRate`

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("MyCacheRefresher-pool-%d")
            .setPriority(1)
            .build();

    public UserTokenCacheService(CacheConfig cacheConfig) {
        idsTokenApplication = new IdsTokenApplication();
        cacheScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(threadFactory);
        buildCache(cacheConfig);
    }


cacheScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> tokenCache.refresh(KEY), 0,
                cacheConfig.getReloadCache(), TimeUnit.valueOf(cacheConfig.getReloadCacheTimeUnit()));
```